# Start remote debugging automatically without manual intervention in clion

Tags: remote-debugging, clion

The feature to use remote debugging seems missing deploy step of some sort.

The only way I was able to come close to remote debugging without doing it manually was to create 2 before launch steps.

1 - Transfer binary to remote machine.

2 - Start GDBServer  ( And the problem is here )

Clion is waiting for that task to finish, but it can't since gdbserver is listening to a port and waiting for a connection.

My work around so far was to create a bash script to run gdbserver in a process in the background, however I lose the output of my software.

Can I capture the gdb output to a new terminal that I could open?

Is there a way to automate the process like in QtCreator?

What are your solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, there is no such feature out of the box yet. And in fact, if I were you, I would probably end up with a similar workaround.

It is a common request and here're the related issues on our tracker:

- [CPP-7160 Launch gdbserver locally and then attach to it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7160)
- [CPP-7050 Launch remote targets (e.g. via ssh using gdbserver)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7050)
- [CPP-744 Remote projects/toolchains support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-744)

Please feel free to vote for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

To what extent this is still related as this answer is 3 years late, I have figured a way to perform a "Non blocking" CMake build with GDB and GDBServer from JLink, without manually starting the GDBServer.

```
add_custom_target(COMMAND /* flashing commands */
                  COMMAND cd "path/to/jlink" && start JLinkGDBServerCL -select /* args... */
                  )
```

The `start` command prevents CLion/CMake to from thinking that the project is still building, while it is not.